# "Search in File" [sometimes] not working in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

As can be seen in the screenshot a "Find" for the pattern `top_20pct_features` is coming up empty-handed even though two matches are visible in the editor pane. Why would this be happening? Note that no special options like 'Full Word' or 'regex' have been selected.

[image]

Comment: What do you have in "filter"? Last icon. Maybe *except strings literals*?

Comment: There's nothing in the filter; you can see that in the icon to the far right is *grayed out*

Comment: Copy to an hex editor and check byte per byte. Maybe you have some letters from a different script.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi see my answer below.   I did not change anything in the search bar but after browsing other files and coming back to this one it started behaving properly.  Intellij/pycharm/Dataspell/etc are great but over the years i've noticed search sometimes fails inexplicably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After editing a different file I came back to this one and with the *same* search term the expected search results are appearing

[image]

I'm not sure what was going on there. It is apparently something to keep in mind that `Pycharm` search occasionally does behave incorrectly.